# discord bot sharding, and handling objects from array results

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so I've read the docs regarding broadcastEval etc (https://discordjs.guide/sharding/extended.html#using-functions-continued )

I'm trying to learn how to shard my bot, and the searches aren't that fruitful unfortunately.  My question:

```
async function serverLookup(client, { sID, authNm }) {
    console.log(`serverID is: ${sID}`);
    console.log(`authNm is: ${JSON.stringify(authNm)}`);

    const svrInfo = await client.guilds.fetch(sID);
    ...
}

await bot.shard.broadcastEval(serverLookup, { context: { sID: serverID, authNm: msgAuthor } })
     .then(async (server) => {
        dispName = server;
        ...
    })
```

I understand "server" will be an array of objects, which have lost their original true object representation.  The documentation says to "***This means none of the convenience methods usually provided to you are available.*** If this is a problem for you, you will want to handle the item inside the broadcastEval"

So in the example there was a called helper function, and the implication was that calls inside this function would then have object property scope.  My code above has 2 snippets, the first being that helper function.  The `client.guilds.fetch` also returns an array and not an object .  Should I "construct" a new guild object to access the methods i want, or is there a better way to handle this?

Ultimately I'm trying to start with a message object, and get to the users list of a server, to access nicknames.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getAuthDispNameFromShardMgr(msg) {
    const bot = msg.client;
    let dispName = '';

    dispName = await bot.shard.broadcastEval(async (client, { guildId, authId }) => {
        if(client.guilds.cache.has(guildId)) {
            // this is the shard that has this guild
            const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);

            // now we have the guild, get the member.
            const member = await guild.members.fetch(authId);
            // console.log(`member is: ${member.nickname}`);
            return member.nickname;
        }
    }, { context: { guildId: msg.guild.id, authId: msg.author.id } })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

    return dispName.find(res => !!res) || null;
}
```